# Are nested methods/functions/coroutines in C# allowed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, nested

```
 public void StartNewWave(float startDelay)
 {

     StartCoroutine(StartDelay());

     IEnumerator StartDelay()
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
         Timer.StartTimerFrom(startDelay, StartWave);
     }
 }
```

In this case its a wrapper around coroutine. I am also interested in regular nested methods.

Comment: What happened when you tried it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Local functions are allowed since [C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#local-functions)

Comment: Great, thanks for help!